# error MSB8040: Spectre-mitigated libraries are required for this project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, wdk

I have a problem that I cannot solve. My code:

```
#include "ntddk.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT theDriverObject,
    IN PUNICODE_STRING theRegistryPath)
{
    DbgPrint("Hello World!");
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

My goal is to run this program without any problems. Error message:

- error MSB8040: Spectre-mitigated libraries are required for this
  project. Install them from the Visual Studio installer (Individual
  components tab) for any toolsets and architectures being used. Learn
  more: https://aka.ms/Ofhn4c

  I added some libraries but the error still apears. Added toolsets:
- C++ ATL for the latest build tools version 142 (ARM)
- C++ ATL for the latest build tools version 142 (ARM64)
- C++ ATL for the latest build tools version (x86 i x64)
- C++ ATL for the latest build tools version 142 with countermeasures for the Specter vulnerability (ARM)
- C++ ATL for the latest build tools version 142 with countermeasures for the Specter vulnerability (ARM64)
- C++ for the latest build tools version 142 with countermeasures for the Specter vulnerability (x86 i x64)

Could someone guide me step by step how to solve it?

Comment: Is this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/spectre-mitigations-in-msvc/ and the `/Qspectre` compiler option, maybe, what you are looking for? (Note that you'd need to recompile *all* code, including libraries you use, with `/Qspectre` to take full advantage)

Comment: See [/Qspectre](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/qspectre?view=vs-2019) documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/spectre-mitigations-in-msvc and the `/Qspectre` compiler option, is probably, what you are looking for? (Note that you'd need to recompile all code, including libraries you use, with [/Qspectre](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/qspectre?view=vs-2019) to take full advantage).