# cannot Debug the Virtual serial port Driver for windows

Tags: serial-port, kernel, virtual, com-port

this is my first time writing driver
I found the virtual serial port from [**microsoft**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-driver-samples/virtual-serial-driver-sample/) and I tried to run it but it's get this error **( I didn't change the code )**

```
Spectre-mitigated libraries are required for this project.
Install them from the Visual Studio installer (Individual components tab)
for any toolsets and architectures being used.
Learn more: https://aka.ms/Ofhn4c   fakemodem (FakeModem\fakemodem)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets
```

this is the image of the Error List
[Error List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HjT3.png)

Comment: In a situation similar to these article? [error MSB8040: Spectre-mitigated libraries are required for this project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59479631/9014308), [Spectre mitigations in MSVC](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/spectre-mitigations-in-msvc/), [To use WDK in VS2019, which Spectre-mitigated library should be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58811910/9014308)

Comment: @kunif yes thank you